# In Spring MVC cannot fetch new uploaded photos in static resource folder in real-time

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I using Intelij IDE and Spring MVC.

When I uploading photos to

> /resource/static/images

I need to wait maybe 30 seconds - 1 minute to see this new uploaded photos on page.

I tried solution to manual refresh (open/closed) static resource folder in IDE with photos and this solution worked not well but in 10 seconds I see new photos.

Do you know how intelij can track automatic changes in resource folder or do you know better solution for this problem ?

Maybe disable caching images folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe we need to clean it and re-build the project. This is happening for me, every time I added a new static file, I need to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Yes but I need to do this after every image was uploaded? Do you know any better way ? @BernardNongpoh

Comment: Currently, IntelliJ does not provide good support for Hot reloading. You can try Springboot developer tools (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-devtools) or if can afford to pay Jrebel (https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) is the best for fast development for java application

Comment: For spring-boot-devtools you mean on number 4.) LiveReload? Yes this maybe will works. In intelJ when you click File -> Syncronize this works but I need to automate this process after uploading image. Do you know how to do that? @BernardNongpoh

Comment: Will let you know if I am able to do that. Currently, I am not sure @Mirko

Comment: Thanks for helping me @BernardNongpoh.

Answer (score 0):

You mean, you try to access the image via img html tag (img src="/image-name.jpg") ? If yes, it is better to provide Spring MVC endpoint with mapping and path variable https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-return-image-file ;
And use this endpoint in the src attribute.

Comment: That is not what I want. I only need to refresh project or syncronize project automatically.